# How do I make default key pair values removable in a VSCode extension contributes configuration schema?

Tags: vscode-extensions, jsonschema

[image]

I have a setting in my VSCode extension of type `object` that I would like the key value pairs of to be optional/removable, but still be default values.
The image above shows the UI representation of the setting, where on the right side the only two options/icons (that appear when hovering on the pair) are to either modify the key value pairs or reset them to the default values, modifying the key creates another pair instead of modifying the current one.

[image]

And as you can see, (on hover) new items are modifiable and removable, unlike the others.

Here's the `contributes` section from my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "configuration": [
      {
        "title": "MyExtension",
        "properties": {
          "myextension.field.CMakeListsTestTemplateReplacements": {
            "type": "object",
            "default": {
              "template": "${baseFileName}",
              "TEMPLATE": "${baseFileNameUpper}",
              "/src_file\\.c": "/${relativeFilePath}"
            },
            "additionalProperties": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "required": [],
            "scope": "resource",
            "markdownDescription": "..."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Settings of type `array` on the other hand, you can remove default items from them, the behavior is not the same with `object`s.

I'm also suspecting this is something unusual in VSCode, but not more than the chance of me not understanding how to use `JSON schema` for this specific case

I've tried a lot of `JSON schema`'s ways of defining an object's structure but the setting's key value pairs are always irremovable in the UI of VSCode's settings

I know that I can try to set them programmaticly after the extension is installed and have the `default` value as an empty `object`, but what I want to know is whether it is possible through the `package.json` or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to define default key-values you have to set a scheme that allows to remove a default key-value by setting a key to a value like `__delete__` in one of the settings files, you will remove the key from the object in the code

Comment: @rioV8 so what you mean is: if I add `__delete__` to the start of the key string value, then the key-value pair will then become deletable?

Comment: no you have to implement the delete yourself in your code when you get the config, use a value that will not happen in a regular situation

Comment: `I know that I can try to set them programmaticly...`


Again, I don't want the programmatic solution, I want to know the way to do it through the `package.json` definition itself, or if not a simple "no, there is no way, for the meantime"

Comment: all settings are merged across the levels, you can't delete settings by setting them. The settings GUI can't handle every possible case, What you want is a collection of possible defaults, so there is no default, what you can do is make each default entry a separate on/off setting so the user can toggle if he wants that key-value added to the `CMakeListsTestTemplateReplacements`, you have to add them to the object by code, each toggle has a default true/false setting.

Comment: Then why would the items in a `default` value - when the setting type is `array` - be removable?

Comment: because VSC makes a copy of the default value in your global/workspace setting and remove the item, and arrays are **NOT** merged as objects are